# Apparent change in bond order of a molecule after an amber simulation?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, amber

I have been following along with [this tutorial for simulating a small ligand binding a protein receptor](https://ambermd.org/tutorials/basic/tutorial4b/index.php).

In both the tutorial and my follow-along (which uses the same commands as the tutorial but with different input), the [input ligand](https://ambermd.org/tutorials/basic/tutorial4b/files/sustiva.pdb) has clear double bonds. However, after re-generating the  ligand pdb after simulation with amber, [the ligand is then represented](https://ambermd.org/tutorials/basic/tutorial4b/files/1FKO_sus_min.pdb) as having only single bonds.

Does this mean that during the simulation the ligand was also considered to only have single bonds?

Comment: What makes you think there are an issue with bond orders? Bond lengths in the output structure are surely OK. The only potential problem I see is that there are no hydrogens on Me-group in output, and that is strange considering that an all-atom force field was used.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Was the comment by @IvanChernyshov helpful? Please update us!